# How to GRANT permissions to a SQL role to create and manage temp tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I'd like to grant permissions to a SQL role to create a temp table #foo and grant permissions to do anything with that table (SELECT, INSERT and DELETE). How is it possible if the table #foo is not created (the user that belongs to this role will create and manage it)?

Thanks

NOTE: If possible, the solution should work with both SQL 2008 and SQL Azure.

Comment: AFIK all logins have permissions to `create` #temp tables and then perform CRUD on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, a user created with `AUTHORIZATION dbo` will already have a right to create and manage a temp table once he is connected to the database. It is only when this user needs to access other tables in the database, he needs explicit permissions granted to him.

Answer (score 2):

You can't:

*Global temporary tables are automatically dropped when the **session that created the table ends and all other tasks have stopped referencing them**. The association between a task and a table is maintained only for the life of a single Transact-SQL statement. This means that a global temporary table is dropped at the completion of the last Transact-SQL statement that was actively referencing the table when the creating session ended.*
[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about Azure, but ...

If you explicitly create a table in the tempdb, it persists across sessions, but will be cleaned out upon server reboot.

```
create table tempdb..authors (au_id char(11))
```

If you create a ##TempTable it is globally visible, but it also ends with the creator's session.