# how to give user permission to create #temptables only

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have database user calling stored procedures, had to give that permission. By default this user is data reader.

Some stored procedures rely on temp tables, how do I allow user to create temp tables but make sure she can't create real ones or modify schema, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Any user can create a temporary table](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2013/05/security-questions-what-permissions-are-required-to-create-temporary-tables/) and [no special permissions are required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4728698/1324345).

Temp tables are scoped to the session that created them, so only that user will have access to the table and once their connection/session is terminated, the temp tables disappear.